# How do I go back to previous screen on pressing back button in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

When Clicked on a button on screen, Camera will be opened. I saw few posts on stack overflow regarding this question. I tried `finish()`, `finishActivity()`, `onBackPressed()` methods after `dispatchTakePictureIntent();` in `onClick` method but then failed! It **exits** my entire app.

This are the excerpts from my [full code](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/upload-image-to-firebase/blob/master/MainActivity.java):

Button's `onClick` method:

```
 mCaptureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.d("TAG", "Camera opened");
          dispatchTakePictureIntent();
      }
  });
```

This method dispatches Intent:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.pc.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

> My Question is, How do I go back to the previous screen when the back
>   button is pressed  when I'm on Camera's Intent.

Comment: You have to do nothing. Android system will handle that for you.

Comment: But when I'm pressing back button in the Camera module, It exits my app. @NaweenNiroshan

Comment: Check in AndroidManifest whether you have set android:noHistory="true" for your activity.

Comment: Sorry! It doesn't work! But, I have only one activity i.e., main activity. @NaweenNiroshan

Comment: on back pressed it automatically redirect to previous screen. i have implemented it in many apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thus you have to do Nothing :
```

> you cant override methods in external activities you are calling.
>   However, when a user hits back in an activity that was called using
>   startActivityForResult the response code RESULT_CANCELLED is generally
>   returned (there may be instances where this isn't true). In your
>   onActivityResult method simply check for the RESULT_CANCELLED code and
>   call whatever functionality you need

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using startActivityForResult and check if your onActivityResult gets called or on back press Activity's onResume gets called

Comment: @PC does it helped?